# Touchpad palm sensitivity

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, synaptics

I'm using (K)ubuntu 12.04 LTS with a Synaptics touchpad. The palm sensitivity it terrible, whenever I'm typing the mouse suddenly jerks off to a different place. Is there a way to enable/increase palm sensitivity?

Comment: @mikewhatever I do not want to disable touchpad tapping. I just want to increase palm sensitivity so that a palm touch is not sensed as a finger touch. Of what I know, it is possible to change the maximum "area of contact" in order to function, but I'm not sure. But I definitely don't want to disable tapping.

Comment: Alright, let's keep it as a fallback option then.

Comment: If this is an "exact duplicate", can someone link me to the question? As I said in my comment, I do NOT want to disable tapping

Comment: @everyone: I have to disagree that this is a duplicate question. This is a very valid question and becomes more valid with the new supersmooth touchpads which Ubuntu constantly fail to handle properly out of the box.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AFAIK, palm sensing is not exposed through the graphical touchpad configuration tool. That said, you could try playing with it by using `synclient`.

To see what options are available, run `synclient -l | grep -i palm`

```
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
```

Those are the options I see, so, to activate the palm sensing, run `synclient PalmDetect=1`, and then experiment with the values of the other two.

```
   "PalmMinWidth" "integer"
          Minimum finger width at which touch is considered a palm.  Prop‐
          erty: "Synaptics Palm Dimensions"

   "PalmMinZ" "integer"
          Minimum  finger  pressure  at  which touch is considered a palm.
          Property: "Synaptics Palm Dimensions"
```

When you find the right values, create a startup entry in Startup Applications with a command of the following form:

```
synclient PalmDetect=1 PalmMinWidth=xx PalmMinZ=yy
```

...where xx and yy are the desired values.

Comment: Seems to work when I test it, but periodically I still get accidental palm touchpad click events that move the cursor.  GUess I need to play with the values again since the defaults weren't good at detecting my palm.  Crazy these options are not available through settings, somehow.

Comment: For my ASUS S-200, which has an ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad, I found good settings were PalmMinWidth=5 and PalmMinZ=20.  YPMV.  (Your palms may vary)

Comment: the values @ngm used also work fine on a ThinkPad T410

Answer (score 2):

Besides the settings posted by `mikewhatever`, these settings seems to work very good for me:

```
synclient AreaLeftEdge=2000 
synclient AreaRightEdge=5000
```

> Note: those are the settings for my device... you need to find out
>   your device values.
>
> Try incrementing AreaRightEdge starting from zero until you can move
>   the cursor as "normal". AreaLeftEdge works the opposite, so from zero,
>   increment it until it doesn't move... then go back little by little
>   until the cursor moves as "normal" again. (at the end, AreaRightEdge
>   can not be lower than AreaLeftEdge).

Perhaps Top and Bottom should be set as well... I will test that later, but at least Left/Right seems to do the job.

Also, in terms of "sensitivity", you can adjust these:

```
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 50
```

As the above values, try to find those that are optimal for you.

(Quoted from my answer to my own question:)
[Synaptics Touchpad : solving 2 finger problem triggered by resting palm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229311/synaptics-touchpad-solving-2-finger-problem-triggered-by-resting-palm/772103#772103)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to lepe's excellent answer: I was able to discover the AreaLeftEdge and AreaRightEdge numbers by using

> user@t560:~$ xinput list

and in there is a line like

> ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

and then taking the device number and feeding it to

> xinput --test 11

and then dragging my finger across the pad, noting the numbers that corresponded to where I wanted the borders to be.

In my case (Thinkpad T560), the extremes of the pad are about 2200 and 4400, so I ended up setting 2700 and 3700 as my left and right edges.